# Unable to resolve nuget packages issue while pulling the project from TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, nuget-package

So my coworker has been working on the .NET C# unit test project on his local and checking in everything into company's TFS server. He is the only person who was working on it. When I was asked to switch to his project I pulled his work from TFS using Visual Studio into my local (kind of creating a copy). So I proceed with **Team** => **Manage Connections** => **Connected to the TFS** => found the desired project folder. Right clicking on this folder in TFS and selecting **Get Latest Version** copied the entire folder to my local, that I explicitly provided in Visual Studio. Once this has been done I selected **File** => **Open** => **Project/Solution** => found **.sln** file on my local folder for just pulled project and selected it. It seems like I have all the code in place, and navigating to the **Managing Nuget Packages** for the solution displays all the same packages as my coworker has on his local Visual Studio. The problem comes when I try to build my newly opened solution, I see a lot of errors which are all referred to inability for the project to refer to the correct assemblies or missing dlls. From my understanding the project is trying to find nuget packages and just can't see it. I'm seeing the same versioning of the packages as my coworker has. Methods that I already tried and they didn't help are below

1. Right click on the solution in Visual Studio Solution Explorer and selecting **Restore Nuget Packages**
2. Tried to copy **packages.config** file from my coworker Visual Studio
3. Tried to run nuget restore MyProject.sln in Package Manager Console
4. Tried to delete folder **package** inside the Solution on my local and copy / paste it from my coworker local
5. Uninstalling all the packages and reinstalling them again in Nuget Package window.

Please share your experiences if you ever was able to resolve this sort of issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to resolve nuget packages issue while pulling the project from TFS

You can try to use the NuGet command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

to force reinstall the package references into project.

What have you tried the methods 1 ~ 4 are restore packages. **NuGet Restore only restores files in the packages directory (\packages folder ), but does not restore files inside your project or otherwise modify your project**. For example, if a package has added some reference DLLs or other files in your project, if you delete any of these files, they will not be re-added when restoring this package. This may cause the your project to not be able to find the missing dependencies when building.

However, I not sure why uninstalling and reinstalling are not works for you. If the package inside the solution under the source control, try to make it out of source control. And please check your project file, make sure the `HintPath` of all packages are correctly.

If above not resolve your issue, please share us the error log after use the command line `Update-Package -reinstall`.

Comment: While I'm running update-package -reinstall I'm getting Access Denied pop up inside Visual Studio. I ask our software architect to take a look. Will let you know once it's fixed or not. Thanks.